# Django Hit Count ImportError

Tags: python, django, hitcounter

I am trying to use the django hitcount, and I am following the only tutorial out there for it https://django-hitcount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html, and I am getting stuck on step 2--adding hitcount to the list of installed apps. When I do that, and try and run the server, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding'
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'hitcount',
    'auctionitem.apps.AuctionitemConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Why!

Comment: will need to see the code

Comment: What would you like to see.  The only thing I've done was install hitcount, and added to the list of installed apps.

Comment: Isn't this related to using python 2? are you using python 2 or 3? what version of django are you using?

Comment: Are you using Django 3?  That decorator doesn't seem to be in utils.encoding any more but it is in Django 2.2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.encoding

Comment: @marke yes sir.  I'm using python 3.

Comment: My guess is that this package doesn't support your Django version as @FiddleStix says

Comment: This has nothing to do with python3, django-hitcount supports Django 2.2 and python 3.5+ (but also still python 2.7). It just doesn't support Django 3.0, which removed support for python 2 entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of django-hitcount now supports Django 3.x.